# How to do CORS the right way?

Tags: javascript, http, security, nginx, cors

My objective is to restrict access to web application to any requests who don't have origin = http://localhost:3000

So after a bit a searching the internet I was able to come up (well, copy-paste) with this configuration:

```
location / {
    set $cors '';
    if ($http_origin ~ 'http://localhost:3000') {
        set $cors 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

     proxy_pass http://10.131.20.142:8000/131j3yc1;
     proxy_set_header received-from "nginx";
     access_log /dev/stdout upstream_log;
}
```

And I tested it to see how it behaves. When I send a request with origin `http://localhost:3000` it sends 200 OK with CORS headers. When I send request with no origin or different origin it still sends 200 OK but without the CORS headers. When browser get's the response with CORS header, it works fine but when CORS headers are not present, it throws an exception like this:

[image: browser cors error]

I am trying to understand what is this CORS configuration protecting here?

1. The origins are plain headers - anyone can send any origin via nginx/curl
2. Even when you send a wrong or no origin, you still get the data with 200

I am guessing either my config is wrong because it doesn't protect app against cross origin requests effectively OR my understanding of CORS is not correct.

Could someone help me figure what am I doing/understanding wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at https://Enable-CORS.org?

Comment: It's unclear what behaviour you were expecting, that seems correct to me. But note that you generally don't set the CORS headers only for requests from the allowed domains, and your description of the behaviour you want isn't really what CORS is.

Comment: Make sure to disable your cache while testing your configuration, `Access-Control-Max-Age` will cause caching to potentially mislead you

Comment: CORS configuration isn’t a means for causing a server to block requests. Instead it’s just a way for server to tell browsers whether they want browsers to allow frontend JavaScript code to access responses from cross-origin requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069689/node-cors-not-denying-requests/45069745#45069745 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432743/will-asp-net-core-cors-policy-prevent-resource-access-from-non-browser-requests/43432787#43432787 etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using *more_set_headers* instead of *add_header*:

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS';
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
etc
```

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 by doing:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras