# My NGINX is not blocking requests using cors

Tags: express, nginx, cors, reverse-proxy, pm2

I have an `express nodejs` application running with `PM2` and a reverse proxy in NGINX in ubuntu EC2.

I want Nginx blocks requests from all origins UNLESS it's https://example.com. I have the config file above but it's still accept any requests.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name api.mysite.com;

  location / {
    # Proxy request to the backend API
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Set CORS headers
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://example.com"; 
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS"; 
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization"; 
  }
}
```

I've tried change many times. Using CORS in express too but no results.

Comment: CORS is not meant to block anything, but to relax some of the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS-enabled server not denying requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069689/cors-enabled-server-not-denying-requests)