# Why am I not getting CORS error after making http request on my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, cors

I have deployed my Express.js application on AWS EC2 ubuntu and installed and configured ngnix.
When I make get request to my API using postman, result is successful without CORS error.
I don't understand why.

My Express.js application does not have app.user(cors()) therefore cors should be blocking all requests by default.

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;  # Your Node.js server's address
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # Pass through the Origin header from the client
        proxy_set_header Origin $http_origin;

        # Enable CORS
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;

        # Handle preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;
        }
    }
    
    # Other server configurations, if any
}
```

Express is running on port 5000

When I make get request to my API on ec2 instance from postman or anywhere else, I don't want it to be successful.

Can anyone explain reason why am I not getting results I want ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS-enabled server not denying requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069689/cors-enabled-server-not-denying-requests)

Comment: If I don't want anyone to make get or post request from postman or other origins, what should I do ?

Comment: Implement access control on the server side.

Comment: As the CORS is enabled in nginx config file `# Enable CORS` section, hence any domain is able to access the URL as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` refers to the `$http_origin` variable which is equivalent to the invoking domain.

Comment: I have tried replacing $http_origin with "www.my-domain.com" and I still got the same result. Cors not denying request