# Lambda Function's Function URL still accessible Globally despite CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I am having an issue where my lambda function is accessible by anyone using the function URL.
My set up is the following (also see screenshots):

-CORS on my function URL allowing only my cloudfront distribution to access it.
-Authorization is none
-No problems with using my lambda function

[screenshot of cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VjCy.png)

[screenshot of permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEcPK.png)

I am trying to restrict my lambda function to not work when anyone opens it. It should only work when I click on the cloudfront link (the cloudfront goes to an s3 bucket which has some html-javascript page which loads the function)

Regards

[tried using cors with the settings in the screenshots. I was expecting the function url to not work when accessing it directly]

Comment: CORS is for protecting the users of browsers from cross site scripting attacks.  It is not a method for controlling access.  Browsers enforce CORS; it's completely irrelevant for non-browser requests.

Comment: @erik258 No, [CORS is no defence](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/948831079649169408), and certainly not against XSS attacks. But you're right that not all user agents implement the SOP and CORS, and that CORS is no substitute for server-side authorization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS-enabled server not denying requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069689/cors-enabled-server-not-denying-requests)

Comment: @erik258 thanks. So how do i prevent access to the lambda function. I have been googling for a while.